# Implicit Function Plotting using MATPLOTLIB's Contour not working

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour, implicit

I'm trying to plot an implicit function:

yx^2 + y^2x = x + y +xy

using Contour but find that the graph doesn't plot correctly.  Example code is shown below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

delta = 0.02
xrange = np.arange(-10, 10, delta)
yrange = np.arange(-10, 10, delta)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(xrange,yrange)

# F is one side of the equation, G is the other
F = Y*X*X - Y*Y*X
G = X + Y + X*Y
plt.contour((F - G), [0])
plt.show()
```

The plot that this code produces: [Incorrect plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3q0Dn.png).

What the plot should look like: [Correct Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dd6Gw.png).

What can I do to better plot this function?  Is there a way that I can rearrange it to get it to plot better?

Answer (score 0):

You simply wrote the wrong equation: the left hand side of your equation is an addition, but you wrote a subtraction. Let's fix that:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

delta = 0.02
xrange = np.arange(-10, 10, delta)
yrange = np.arange(-10, 10, delta)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(xrange,yrange)

# F is one side of the equation, G is the other
F = Y*X*X + Y*Y*X
G = X + Y + X*Y
plt.contour((F - G), [0])
plt.show()
```

[image]